# Why did Commissioner Gordon say this line: "Don't have to see the sky to know it's a full moon"...?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

Dr. Stone realizes that Mother Box was taken by Cyborg, then he was startled by a Parademon which landed behind him. The scene cuts to Gotham Police Department, where Commissioner Gordon receives a bundles of messages from a female officer, then walks side-by-side with Detective Crispus Allen:

> Commissioner Gordon: **Don't have to see the sky to know it's a full moon**.
>
> Crispus Allen: Half of Gotham's reality-challenged community showed up. Say they saw flying monsters by the harbor.
>
> Commissioner Gordon: You were right, Ma. Police Academy. What's wrong with dental school?

Why did Commissioner Gordon say this line: "Don't have to see the sky to know it's a full moon"...?

Comment: [Lunacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunatic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another expression with the same meaning would be, "You don't have to look up to know it's raining."  In either case, you can infer what is going on in the sky from what you can see on the ground—moonlight or raindrops.  It means you don't need to trace everything back to the source to see what is happening (or sometimes—more loosely—that sufficient circumstantial evidence is enough to tell you everything you need to know).  In this case, parademons coming down out of the sky tells you that an extraterrestrial invasion is underway, even if you haven't found where exactly they are coming from.  ([A boom tube?](https://www.writeups.org/wp-content/uploads/Parademons-Apokolips-DC-Comics-Mignola-h05.jpg)  [A star gate?](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-dfmdcsqsOt60UoT723Gn0mu3GYI_eBINCg&usqp=CAU))

The particular version of the expression used here, mentioning the full moon, also alludes to the the folklore belief that weird or dangerous things are more likely to happen around the full moon.  (I once saw a poster at a behavioral neuroscience conference, in which a couple of graduate students at the [Yerkes National Primate Research Center](http://www.yerkes.emory.edu/) examined whether their chimpanzees got into more fights around the full moon that at other times of the month.)  The irony is that the usual "reality-challenged community" who might, especially around the a full moon, overreact to something that actually had a mundane explanation are quite right that something is up.